# Android web view not sizing properly on rotate. (Using Xamarin)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am encountering an issue when using a custom web view with Xamarin forms where when the device rotates the viewport sizing seems to gets messed up and thinks the device has impossible dimensions.  I will attach screenshots at the end of what this looks like when debugging with Chrome shortly.  Essentially what is happening is when the web view loads up, everything works just fine.  When the device is rotated, height dimension (as confirmed by javascript) shoots up to the height of all interior elements.  When rotated back to it's original position, the height dimension remains messed.  This creates an issue where part of the screen is not visible and cannot be scrolled to.

Here's the Renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HybridWebView), typeof(HybridWebViewRenderer))]
namespace DashXF.Droid
{
    public class HybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<HybridWebView, HSRWebView>
    {
        const string JavaScriptFunction = "function invokeCSharpAction(data){jsBridge.invokeAction(data);}";

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);


            if (Control == null)
            {
                var webView = new HSRWebView(this.Context);

                Android.Webkit.WebView.SetWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);

                webView.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.MatchParent);
                webView.Settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
                webView.SetWebViewClient(new GeoWebViewClient());
                webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                webView.SetInitialScale(1);
                webView.Settings.LoadsImagesAutomatically = true;
                webView.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
                webView.Settings.DatabaseEnabled = true;
                webView.Settings.SetAppCacheEnabled(true);
                webView.Settings.SetGeolocationEnabled(true);
                webView.Settings.SetGeolocationDatabasePath(webView.Settings.DatabasePath);
                webView.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;
                webView.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
                webView.ScrollBarStyle = Android.Views.ScrollbarStyles.OutsideOverlay;
                webView.ScrollbarFadingEnabled = false;
                webView.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClientCustom(Forms.Context));
                SetNativeControl(webView);
            }
            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                Control.RemoveJavascriptInterface("jsBridge");

                Control.ClearHistory();

                var hybridWebView = e.OldElement as HybridWebView;
                hybridWebView.Cleanup();
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Control.AddJavascriptInterface(new JSBridge(this), "jsBridge");

                if (Element.Uri.StartsWith("http"))
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Navigating to: " + Element.Uri);
                    Control.LoadUrl(Element.Uri);
                    InjectJS(JavaScriptFunction);
                }
                else
                {
                    Control.LoadUrl(string.Format("file:///android_asset/Content/{0}", Element.Uri));
                    InjectJS(JavaScriptFunction);
                }
            }
        }

        void InjectJS(string script)
        {
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.LoadUrl(string.Format("javascript: {0}", script));
            }
        }

        private class GeoWebViewClient : WebViewClient
        {
            public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ShouldOverrideUrlLoading:" + url);

                if (url.StartsWith("mailto:") || url.StartsWith("tel:"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView,
                            Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url));
                    Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }

                // When user clicks a hyperlink, load in the existing WebView
                view.LoadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

        }
        private class WebChromeClientCustom : WebChromeClient
        {
            private readonly Context _context;

            public WebChromeClientCustom(Context context )
            {
                _context = context;
            }

            public override void OnGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(string origin, GeolocationPermissions.ICallback callback)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Asking for location permission.");

                callback.Invoke(origin, true, false);

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here's the MainActivity:

```
[Activity(Label = "App",
    Icon = "@drawable/icon",
    Theme = "@style/MainTheme",
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
```

Here's the HSRWebview:

```
public class HSRWebView : WebView 
{
    public HSRWebView(Context context) : base ( context )
    {

    }

    public override bool OnKeyDown([GeneratedEnum] Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (keyCode == Keycode.Back && CanGoBack())
        {
            if (!Url.Contains("/?Team")) // assuming this is root level
            {
                GoBack();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("URL: " + Url);
                return true;
            }
        }

        return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
    }
}
```

Here are some screen grabs of what is happening on screen rotation - you'll notice that the window.innerHeight will jump to 1200px (the total height of the content on the page).  The first of each pair of images is what I see on my screen vs the second which is the chrome web view debugger:

[Screenshot before rotate (can be scrolled here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKViS.png)
[Debugger image before rotate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRPLl.png)

[Screenshot after rotate - landscape (can no longer be scrolled)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1Eqm.png)
[Debugger image after rotate - landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUp4Q.png)

[Screenshot after rotate - portrait (still cannot be scrolled)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnZk7.png)
[Debugger image after rotate - portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfnMh.png)

Comment: What is your `HSRWebView`? I used official demo [HybridWebView Custom Renderer](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/CustomRenderers/HybridWebView) for testing, couldn't reproduce your issue. Besides, I can only see the first image from your post.

Comment: `HSRWebView` is just a `Android.Webkit.WebView` - I am adding it to the question now